# hacer un sort a un array con mongoose

Tags: array, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, ordenamiento

Estoy intentando ordenar el siguiente modelo de manera desc por **comments likes**:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
title:{type:String,required:true},
user:[
    {
      type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:"User"
    },
],
description:{type:String,required:true},
likes:{type:Number},
comments:[{
    user:[
        {
          type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref:"User"
        },
    ],
    message:{type:String,required:true},
    likes:{type:Number}
}],});
```

Esto es lo que he intentado pero el sort no da resultado

```
Post.find().sort('-comments.likes');
Post.find().sort({'comments.likes':-1});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La llave `comments` del documento, según el esquema, es un `array` de `objects`, una solución puede ser obtener el documento del **usuario**, para luego [**desarmar**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) el array de la llave `comments` y regresar un documento con cada uno de sus elementos ordenados por la llave `likes`.

Esta operación se puede realizar con **Aggregation Framework**, incluye este código en tu función de consulta:

```
const database = client.db("nombre_de_db");
//suponiendo que ya tienes el nombre del usuario
const user_param = "nombre_de_usuario";

//consulta de agregación
const agg = [
    {
        '$match': {
        'user': user_param
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
        'path': '$comments', 
        'includeArrayIndex': 'string',
        'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
        }
    }, {
        '$sort': {
        'comments.likes': -1
        }
    }
    ];
//resultados
//ordena los comentarios que tengan mas likes
const commentLikesSortbyUser = await database.collection("nombre_collecion")
.aggregate(agg,{ allowDiskUse: true })
.toArray();

console.log(commentLikesSortbyUser);
```